# Create X509 certificate with v3 extensions using command line tools

Tags: openssl, certificates

I am using the following configuration file named root.conf:

```
[req]
default_bits            = 2048
default_md              = sha256
distinguished_name      = req_dn
prompt                  = no
encrypt_key             = no

[req_dn]
CN                      = 07dda2b49637f71b6cebe87a6954e159313b4372

[x509v3_extensions]
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:true
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
keyUsage                = critical,keyCertSign,cRLSign
subjectInfoAccess       = @sia
certificatePolicies     = critical,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.14.2
sbgp-autonomousSysNum   = critical,@rfc3779_asns
sbgp-ipAddrBlock        = critical,@rfc3997_addrs

[sia]
1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.5;URI  = rsync://example.org/rpki/root/
1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.10;URI = rsync://example.org/rpki/root/root.mft

[rfc3779_asns]
AS.0 = 64496-64511
AS.1 = 65536-65551

[rfc3997_addrs]
IPv4.0 = 192.0.2.0/24
IPv4.1 = 198.51.100.0/24
IPv4.2 = 203.0.113.0/24
IPv6.0 = 2001:0DB8::/32
```

And I am using this command to create the certificate:

```
#!/bin/sh -    
# Generate the root key if it doesn't already exist.
test -f root.key ||
openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048

# Generate the root certificate.
openssl req                     \
-new                    \
-x509                   \
-config root.conf       \
-key    root.key        \
-out    root.cer        \
-outform    DER         \
-days       1825        \
-set_serial 1           \
-extensions x509v3_extensions
```

But I get the following error if I run it using the above config file:

```
Error Loading extension section x509v3_extensions
139978043373216:error:22097081:X509 V3 routines:DO_EXT_NCONF:unknown     extension:v3_conf.c:129:
139978043373216:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:v3_conf.c:93:name=sbgp-autonomousSysNum, value=@rfc3779_asns
```

The above set of code is directly taken from http://rpki.net/wiki/doc/RPKI/CA/Configuration/CreatingRoot

Comment: Probably useless now, but: make sure you are using a build of OpenSSL that was configured to enable RFC3779, which is not the default.

Comment: Do not dare call this an answer - so I'll comment :)

Comment: Do not dare call this an answer - so I'll comment :) - In order to create a self-contained self-signed certificate I used the command: "openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -set_serial 2005100101 -keyout ftpd.pem -out ftpd.pem -days 365". And that gives:"Version: 3 (0x2)". Maybe you can use that command (and "openssl x509 -in ftpd.pem -noout -text | head -5") to see if dave_thompson_085's comment is the key. (the -nodes argument prevents asking for a passphrase) (apology for duplicate - edit timeout)

Answer (score -1):

The syntax should be:

```
openssl x509 -new
```

There is no dash in front of `x509`

Comment: No, this OP does want `openssl req -new -x509` and dashes on `-new` and `-x509` _as options to `req`_ are correct. `x509` is a different operation, not what this OP wants although it is valid in other cases, but it does not have an option `-new`.